# AJAX response showing nothing for different domains

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am testing a AJAX response for a domain in which I will update the news in the admin panel . For testing , I have uploaded a testing HTML page in

http://7sisters.in/bus_response.html

And I have the PHP code in

http://www.bookings.7sisters.in/response/response.php

`response.php` code is:

```
<?php

    echo 'JSON RESPONSE';
?>
```

But the AJAX response `ajaxRequest.responseText` alerts empty. Is this due to the difference in domain ?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6809053/486349

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can not do cross domain ajax call for security reasons however there are libraries (jQuery, mootools) which can do it in little different way