# Webservice POST through JQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I have a restful webservice and i am trying to make a HTTP POST request via a jquery call through my web pages.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/newjavascript.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="intialize()"/>
<script>
function formToJSON() {
  return JSON.stringify({"name": $('#name').val() });
 }
  </script>

  <script>
   function intialize(){
   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   url: "http://localhost:41191/test/resources/storeincompleteform",
   dataType: "json",
   data: formToJSON(),
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert(' success');

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error: ' + textStatus);
    }
  });

      }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

But the above code is not working.The webservice is working properly

Comment: The alert shows an error message

Comment: Also.. why are you importing jQuery twice? 1.5 and 1.7?.. and always load jQuery before dependent .js files

Comment: What do you mean by not working - is it gives you an error, or nothing happens?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki what does the error say?

Comment: My guess is you've never heard of the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests)

Answer (score 0):

Your script is posting to a different port. This conflicts with the browser's [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests).

If you're trying to **retrieve** data from a server, you can use [jQuery's](http://www.haykranen.nl/2011/02/25/jquery-1-5-and-jsonp-requests/) [built-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) [JSONP](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/) technology in combination with some [server-side scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-example) to circumvent this.

However, since in your case you're trying to **post** data to a server, you have two options:

1. Ensure the *XMLHttpRequest* is same-orgin
2. Make use of the [cross-domain XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) technology available in modern browsers; in that case, you'll have to configure your server to serve `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers that permit the site you're posting from.

Answer (score 0):

This is an XSS issue, potentially due to the different ports. Change:

```
dataType: "json"
```

to:

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```