# external URL AJAX and JSON PHP side of things

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm aware that modern browsers don't allow AJAX requests to foreign URLS, The workaround is JSON encoding and I'm doing that like this:

```
 function findZipCodesInRadius(userZip, radiusInMiles) {

     $.getJSON("http://mydomain.com/php/zipCodesInRadius.php?callback=?", {
         TheUserZip: userZip,
         TheRadiusInMiles: radiusInMiles
     },

     function (data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
     });


 }
```

and on the PHP side of things I have it "echoing" the results back like this:

```
$JSONData = array("callback"=>"true"); 
echo json_encode($JSONData);
```

After looking around google, the above code is what I've found and it's still not working.
How do I properly echo the callback? Maybe I'm doing the ajax request incorrectly? I usually do it a different way, but because I'm trying to access a file on another website of mine, I've been looking everywhere on the proper way of sending the request and this is what I came up with. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-example

Comment: I was looking for something like that on here. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to implement a callback function in order for this to work. You will need to wrap your json_encode with the callback function which is defined in `$_GET['callback']`.

For example, `echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")";`.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. It was driving me crazy! Totally makes sense now. It will allow me to accept this answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the callback for jsonp requests

```
$JSONData = array("callback"=>"true");
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callback,'(',json_encode($JSONData),')';
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm aware that modern browsers don't allow AJAX requests to foreign URLS,

On the contrary, *modern* browsers allow that, if you tell them to (see [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing))

The workaround is not JSON *encoding* but [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), a technique that uses dynamic `<script>` elements to load the external source. For this to work, the source must be executable JavaScript, this is where the `callback` parameter comes into play:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($JSONData) . ')';
```

The parameter will be a function name, but you don't have to care about that in your JS code, JQuery.getJSON handles it for you transparently.

Comment: Completely makes sense now. Thank you for taking the time to answer this.