# $.Post contains no response

Tags: php, http-headers, .post

I have a `.php` file from another server which processes data. This data is tabulated. So whenever I call this page using `$.post` with the right parameters, its response is nothing. I checked my code and maybe the header is the one responsible for it. What I want actually is to return my tabulated data so that I can populate it to another page. My header is like this, `header("Content-type: application/json");`. What am I missing?

```
$.post('http://333.333.33.33/reporting/table.php?loc_id='+locid+'&loc_type='+loctype+'',{loc_id:locid, loc_type: loctype},function(data){
    $('table#default_table').hide();
    $('div#generated_table').html(data);
});
```

that is how I call my $.post.

Comment: Can we have some code?

Comment: *I have a .php file from another server which processes data* — Sounds ripe for a Same Origin Policy violation. What does your JavaScript console say?

Comment: You need to use JSONP here instead JSON.

Comment: did you chechk the console log? once i too had the same problem but got resolved by adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')` at top of php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You my friend have become yet another victim of the Same Origin Policy - luckily, this can be "worked around" by using a method called JSONP. This does, however, require a GET rather than a POST request. I myself had to use this, and I had no idea about how it worked, so I [asked a question and got a wonderful answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to communicate between 2 different domains right?

You need to use JSONP here instead JSON.
[Check Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)