# send data from javascript to php (phonegap android)

Tags: php, javascript, android, database, cordova

how to send data from javascript to php?if i use ajax, there will be error?
here's my code

**script.js**

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://*my_ip*/TA/php/upload.php", win, fail, options);
};
```

**upload.php**

```
include 'db.php';
$t=time();
$id_place = $_GET["id_place"];
$file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"].$t.".jpg";
$dir_full = "images/full/"."full_".$file_name;
$dir_small = "images/small/"."small_".$file_name;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dir_full);

$im_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir_full);
$src_width = imageSX($im_src);
$src_height = imageSY($im_src);

$dst_width = 50;
$dst_height = ($dst_width/$src_width)*$src_height;

$im = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_width,$dst_height);
imagecopyresampled($im, $im_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dst_width, $dst_height, $src_width, $src_height);

imagejpeg($im, $dir_small);

$temp = "http://*my_ip*/TA/php/images/full/"."full_".$file_name;
$temp2 = "http://*my_ip*/TA/php/images/small/"."small_".$file_name;
//$id_place = .$id_place;
$query = "insert into gallery values ('','$id_place','$temp','$temp2')";
mysql_query($query);

imagedestroy($im_src);
imagedestroy($im);
```

if i use ajax, the script.js will be like this (correct me if im wrong)

**script.js with ajax**

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    jquery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://203.189.122.77/TA/php/gallery.php',
                    data: {id_place: window.localStorage("id_place")},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
                    success: function(data, status){
            //alert(window.localStorage.getItem("id_place"));
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                        options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://203.189.122.77/TA/php/upload.php", win, fail, options, true);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('There was an error when download images');
        }
    });

};
```

if i use ajax, there always be in error function.if im not use ajax, i cannot get id_place

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: That isn't actually JSONP.

Comment: @SLaks so what should i write in my js n php??
dont know what is the error.but it always appear (there was an error when download images)..
and in database, everything is complete (id_place, temp, temp2) but the image is not uploaded..
but when im not use ajax, the file is uploaded but the id_place is missing in my database..it says "0"

Comment: Put a breakpoint within the error callback and look at the local variables. jquery's error handle functions can take arguments, the first of which is the XHR request object.  Within the error function, output the XHR object to the console and look for the error.

Comment: Actually, if you can bring up your F12 console, switch to the network section before you upload a file, then look at the response... that should give you some clues as to the nature of the error.

Comment: Check the return value of `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: the error is "jquery xxx was not called back"

Answer (score 1):

With JSONP, the server does not return a regular JSON object, rather it returns a JavaScript function to be run on the client.  Your client code then executes the function returned from the server for access to the data.

I believe another post: [Simple jQuery, PHP and JSONP example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-)
will explain how to do this in your context.

To understand the mechanics of JSONP more generally, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP might be of use.