# XMLHttpRequest cannot load url and my domain not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to access new web page(different domain) from my current page. for that 
I have used following method.

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"); ?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#content").load("<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>");
});
</script>
```

but it gives me `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://adamsshs.pbworks.com/w/page/44430294/Algebra. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` I have search. most of the them are said to use `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"); ?>` . I have used that one but still same error. what am I missed.

Comment: The access control header needs to be on the server-end of the communication, ie the other website. If they don't set it and don't provide a JSONP API, you'll have to resort to other, non-client-side means

Comment: you mean i need put <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"); ?>   in http://adamsshs.pbworks.com/w/page/44430294/Algebra. is that?

Comment: Yup, good luck with that ;). Alternatively, you could create a local PHP proxy file to fetch the page contents and return them to your JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Is because the cross domain policy.

If you want to called ajax cross domain you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for called cross domain

jquery with JSONP - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp

This is related to your question - [Simple jQuery, PHP and JSONP example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053)