# jQuery Ajax returns "status: 0" only in some cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, mechanicalturk

I have part of a psycholinguistic norming study on Amazon's Mechanical Turk where participants see a picture and then name it out loud. Their voice is recorded via HTML5's audio recording features, and the recording is uploaded to the server. There are three relevant files: the php file which displays the external question (external_question.php), the js file which hands all of the javascript (controller.js), and the php file to accept the file upload (accept_upload.php).

**external_question.php** set for live server:

```
<form id="question_form" name="question_form" action="https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" method="post">
```

**external_question.php** set for sandbox server:

```
<form id="question_form" name="question_form" action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" method="post">
```

Now, for some odd reason, whenever I'm using the live server, the response printed in the console by finalizeRecording() as a response from accept_upload that reads responseText:"", status:0, statusText:"error". (See below for functions and files.) Basically, nothing gets returned.

However, when I use the sandbox server, everything works just fine. The file is uploaded, and my response looks normal:

> readyState: 4, responseText: "Page entered.`<pre>`Audio file successfully processe…↵            [size] => 540716↵       )↵↵)↵`</pre>`", status: 200, statusText: "OK"

I'm stumped! What could be causing my Ajax request to completely fail when I'm submitting the form to one URL, but then work flawlessly when I'm submitting to a different URL?

---

### Relevant Files and Functions

**controller.js** (relevant function)

```
function finalizeRecording( blob ) {
    var myFormData = new FormData();
    myFormData.append('audioFile', blob, 'rec_' + workerId + '_' + stimulusName + '_' + assignmentId + '.wav');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'accept_upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false, // important
        contentType: false, // important
        dataType : 'json',
        data: myFormData,
        complete: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $('form').trigger('submit');
        }
    });;
}
```

**accept_upload.php** (whole file)

```
<?php
echo "Page entered.";

$uploadDir = '../../WHEREVER/WHEREVER/';
chmod('uploads/', 0777);
$uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['audioFile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audioFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) {
    echo "Audio file successfully processed\n";
} else {
    echo "Audio file processing attempt unsuccessful\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: using dataType json but returning  text doesn't make sense

Comment: You are correct, I'm not sure why that's like that. But that wouldn't have an effect on the request not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Cross Domain, you cannot make a call to a URI that is not the origin of the content.  You can however get around this via `CORS` or using `JSONP`.

Here are some of my answers on this:

[JQuery JSON Calls To PHP WebService Always Runs "Error" Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685949/jquery-json-calls-to-php-webservice-always-runs-error-callback/20691993#20691993)

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: But if that's the issue, why is it happening on one server and not the other? Both of them are uploading the file from from a server different than where external_question.php is hosted.