# how to put full response of jsonp in textarea and display the full response in div?

Tags: ajax, jsonp

i am trying to display the full response of jsonp call in textarea and div but for some reason it doesnt work! could any one tell me what i am doing wrong here?Thanks

ajax script:

```
<script>


$(function() {

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",

        dataType: "jsonp",

        cache: false,

        url: "https://api.somesite.com/test&count=-1",


        success: function(data) {

              alert(data);
              $(".response").append(data);
              $("#outputtext").append(data);


             document.myform.outputtext.value = document.myform.outputtext.value+data+'\n' ;



        }

    });

});


</script>

<div class="response"></div>

<form id="myform" name="myform" action="./" method="post">

<td><textarea rows="6" cols="15" name="outputtext" style="width: 99%;"></textarea></td>

</form>
```

Comment: try with $("textarea[name='outputtext']").val(response); whether data returns something ? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-example

Comment: thanks for response . i get [object Object] in the textarea

Comment: You get whole object not a one data, example to use: response.foo