# Run JavaScript after Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a HTML that uses this function for loading another PHP with Ajax:

```
   function LoadContent(n,func)
{           
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState== 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("div-content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        if(typeof(func)==='undefined')
                {
                // nothing
                }
            else
                {
                eval(func);
                }

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",n,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

So far, all OK. The PHP to be loaded generates a HTML which contains a

```
<script> 
function foo() { 
alert('hello'); 
} 
</script>
```

And the original HTML calls the loader with `javascript:LoadContent('file.php','foo()')` , but foo() is not called. The eval() line says "no such function" in Chrome.

How could I manage it so, after Ajax loading, the JavaScript function which would reside in the loaded html would be executed?

Comment: If the HTML you posted is the *response* sent by the server, you also have to add it to the document before you do anything with it. However, I'd argue that this, loading JS from the server and passing a string of JS which should be evaluated after the the content is loaded, is a bad approach.

Comment: Yes it's added to the document, I just shortened the function. I 've edited it.

Comment: Ah. `scripts` added via `innerHTML` are not evaluated by the browser for security reasons (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML#Security_considerations). So your function really doesn't exist. See also [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1197575/218196)

Comment: May want to look into jsonp; see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-example

Comment: Don't do this please.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
javascript:LoadContent('newstandby.php',foo)
```

since `foo` is a function and it is going to get called as a callback it is passed as function and not it is result( `foo()` )

Comment: Same result. foo() undentified.

Comment: That can't work since `foo` doesn't exist yet (at least if I understand correctly).

Comment: It exists when the PHP loads from the Ajax call.