# Open MDB file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I'm currently working on a ionic app with Visual Studio. My final goal is to open a MDB database (Microsoft Access) that is located in a distant server. I suppose that I have to use a PHP file to accomplish it.

So I have a lot of questions:
- Is it possible to communicate with a MDB file througt JS in a Cordova app?
- How to include the PHP file to my JS?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english, I'm not a native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want JS to be able to talk to or change a MDB database, you'll need to build a PHP page on your web server that talks to the MDB database instead, and then talk to the PHP page with Cordova/JS.

Examples: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/

Your PHP page should return JSPONP though (not regular HTML), and you can call your PHP page via jQuery. Here are other examples:

[Simple jQuery, PHP and JSONP example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-example)